# Как получить результат работы функции из потока?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Был такой код:

```
cUpdate.sResult result = cUpdate.Download();
```

Встала необходимость выделить выполнение в поток, т.к. форма подвисает на очень долго. Реализовал так:

```
cUpdate.sResult result;
Thread myt = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { cUpdate.Download(); }));
```

Но как поместить результат работы функции в переменную? Сама функция статическая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В асинхронном программировании это делается так:

```
async void SomeFunction()
{

    // ...

    var result = await Task.Run(() => cUpdate.Download());

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36549/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-------).